# Database php class causes fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a php class that will connect me to the database more easily, but it seems to not work.

This is my function from the class:

```
class Database {
    // host, username, password and db are defined

    public function GetMySqlConnection()
    {
        return mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);
    }
}
```

And I use it in another page like this:

```
$db = Database()->GetMySqlConnection();
$result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['agname']) . "' AND password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['agpass']) . "'");
```

For some reason it causes some error I can't manage to find. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have error text?

Answer (score 1):

`Database` is class here, so you cannot use `$db = Database()->GetMySqlConnection();`

You should use:

```
$db = new Database();
$db = $db->GetMySqlConnection();
```

instead

Comment: Or in newer php versions: `$db = (new Database())->GetMySqlConnection();`

Comment: Or you could make your class a STATIC Class and call it as `Database::GetMySqlConnection()`

Comment: I tried with `new Database()` but it stopped running after executing this function.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to add an include, it works now! ;)